# Preload UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I've tried in my code to preload an UIWebView but without any result.
I can't figure out what is wrong in the code.

First UIViewController

```
func viewDidLoad(){
let gallery = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Gallery") as! GalleryViewController

gallery.loadwWebView()
}
```

In the second UIViewController

```
func loadwWebView(){
let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height))

webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))

self.view.addSubview(webView)

}
```

I've choose the programmatically to create the `UIWebView` way because if I use the @IBOutlet its gonna crash.

Comment: why you are not tried with NSNotification center for your concept, this is alternate choice

Comment: can you show your crash report

Comment: No error, it isn't displayed

Comment: print `self.view`'s dimensions in `loadwWebView`... if its all 0s, try calling it in `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: call your method in `viewDidAppear` and try once

Comment: gallery.loadwWebView()  if is called in viewDidAppear doesn't change nothing

Comment: just wait for some time it will be load, it takes minimum 4 sec to load

Comment: this is not the problem. the webview is never load

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can we talk in chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're instantiating a gallery, which is in turn creating a web view, but `gallery` is a local variable and will be deallocated when it falls out of scope.

You need to keep a reference to this view controller (e.g. make it a property of the current view controller). If you do this, you need to make sure that when you transition to this view controller, you don't use a segue (because that will create a second instance of that second view controller), but rather programmatically transition to the one you already instantiated.

You might also want to save a reference to that web view you added to the second view controller's view hierarchy because otherwise you won't be able to reference it again (or at least not without some cumbersome enumeration of the subviews).